# Truncating a random gammavariate result to an upper limit

Tags: python, random

I want to draw a number from a gammavariate, but I want to set an upper limit.
Why this does not work?

```
import random
[int(random.gammavariate(3, 3)) if x < 21 else 20 for x in range(1)]

Out[59]: [22]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the output you're expecting?

Comment: I ain't no python expert but are you sure x is well-defined when you evaluate  x < 21?

Comment: A number equals to 20 or smaller

Comment: if x < 21 pass... if not 20

Comment: @Bathsheba List comprehension allows this

Comment: Do you have to use list comprehension? I think `x` is always zero so your `else` never executes beside other problems.

Comment: No. Just a fast way to avoid loops and ifs... @sudomakeinstall2 But my doubt is because that was supposed to work... I guess!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why making things [complicated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)?

`x` is always `0` in your list comprehension.

try it this way:

```
x = int(random.gammavariate(3,3))
[x if x < 21 else 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you want to clamp a random value following the [gamma distribution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gammavariate) in a certain range [0-20], you could do it like this:

```
import random


def clamp(x, min_value, max_value):
    return max(min(max_value, x), min_value)

min_value, max_value = 0, 20
print([clamp(int(random.gammavariate(3, 3)), min_value, max_value)
       for v in range(1)])
```

In your example, you were using the index x instead of your random gamma value, I'm assuming that's not what you want